# Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'xelatex -halt-on-error -interactix -shell-escape' with external PGFPlot and TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, xetex, tikz-external

I have been trying to use external PGFPlot and TikZ because I kept running into out-of-memory issues and it seems to externalize the figures into separate pdfs to be cached is the recommended solution. But I keep running into errors whenever I try to externalize the document.

Error:

```
Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'xelatex -halt-on-error -interactix -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that.
```

The error disappears when I forgo attempting to externalize but that is not my goal.

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=2cm]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} % Comment out to make it run without error
\tikzexternalize[prefix=cache/]{main} % Comment out to make it run without error
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external} % Comment out to make it run without error
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.external} % Comment out to make it run without error
\usepackage[binary-units=true]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{groupplot}[
                group style={
                    group size=2 by 1,
                    horizontal sep=40pt,
                    vertical sep=20pt,
                },
                x unit=\si{\byte},
                y unit=\si{\second},
                ]
                
                \nextgroupplot
                \addplot {x};
                
                \nextgroupplot
                \addplot {x^3};
            \end{groupplot}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Text describing the plots.}
    \label{plot:graphs}
    \end{figure}

    Look at plot \ref{plot:graphs} for details.

\end{document}
```

Log File (Full Log [here](https://fileleaks.com/LWlFaqM9dU/main.log)):

```latex
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'xelatex -halt-on-error -intera
ction=batchmode -jobname "cache/main-figure0" "main"' ========
runsystem(xelatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "cache/main-fi
gure0" "main")...disabled (restricted).

\openout3 = `main.auxlock'.


! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'xelatex -halt-on-error -interacti
on=batchmode -jobname "cache/main-figure0" "main"' did NOT result in a usable o
utput file 'cache/main-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:.bmp:). P
lease verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflate
x -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that.
 Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'cache/main
-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.34         \end{tikzpicture}
                              
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.


Overfull \hbox (127.35689pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 17--35
[][] 
 []


LaTeX Warning: Reference `plot:graphs' on page 1 undefined on input line 39.

[1

] (main.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

 )
```

This error only occurs in subfiles with TikZ and PGFPlot resources. It also breaks `\ref` all over my document even though it outputs into a pdf. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but the question is not very clear to me. But first some comments to your code: You load the `external` library three times, `\tikzexternalize` doesn't have a mandatory argument (`{}`). Your error message contains `interactix`. Is this real? Because I would it expect to be `interaction=batchmode` or similar. Does the error also occur with the above given MWE or only "in subfiles with TikZ and PGFPlot resources"? If the latter please modify your MWE accordingly so we can reproduce the error. If the first, does the error also occur when compiling with (Lua)LaTeX?

Comment: I have gotten the same error with or without subfiles. I created this MWE because subfiles are often clunk to just copy-paste and run. My reading leads me to believe I have to externalize PGFPlot and TikZ separately for which there are 3 `external`(s). The `\tikzexternal` argument is there because I want to control where the cache file is stored. With (Lua)LaTeX I get `Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'lualatex -halt-on-error -interact`. I hope I was of assistance.

Comment: There should be a LOG file in the `cache` directory as well. Please add that to your question as well.

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for a comment*

---

You only need to load one of the two `external` libraries. Currently, with TikZ v3.1.9a and PGFPlots v1.18.1, the versions should be identical, so it is just a matter of taste.

When I compile

```
% used PGFPlots v1.18.1
\documentclass[border=5pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{
        groupplots,
        external,
    }
    \tikzexternalize[prefix=cache/]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            group size=2 by 1,
            horizontal sep=40pt,
            vertical sep=20pt,
        },
        xlabel=B,
        ylabel=s,
    ]
    \nextgroupplot
        \addplot {x};
    \nextgroupplot
        \addplot {x^3};
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with LuaLaTeX from an up-to-date MiKTeX, I can see from the log the `\tikzexternal` call

```
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'lualatex -shell-escape -halt-o
n-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "cache/minimal-figure0" "\def\tikzexter
nalrealjob{minimal}\input{minimal}"' ========
```

which works like it should, i.e. I don't get any error message.

Regarding `\ref`. Here it is unclear what you mean. Either you want it to return a number, but for that the `figure` environment is missing. Or you want it to return the plot, but for that you have to move the `\label` after an `\addplot` command. After that you need to compile three times to see the expected result, because in the first run the `axis` environment is externalized and the `\label` is written to the AUX file, in the second run the crossref is externalized and then shows up after the third run.

Comment: Thank you but the errors are still present on my end. With LuaLaTeX:`Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'lualatex -halt-on-error -interact`; with XeTeX:`Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'xelatex -halt-on-error -interacti`, and `running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} into your preamble.` with both. My MikTeX is up-to-date as well. Missing the `figure{}[]` was an oversight on my end. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @Rashiq, the `\ref` still doesn't work because you also need a `\caption` inside the `figure` environment. Have you tested compiling your or my code when you get the errors? In the first case, please try the first one. If you still get the errors, please let us know the TikZ and PGFPlots versions you are using. Maybe also add the full lines from the LOG where the errors appear.

Comment: I have used both mine and yours to generate the above. PGFPlots ver: 1.18.1; TikZ ver: 3.1.9a. I have attached the original question with the log file.